# How to do range query with Datanucleus/JDO?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

What would be the Datanucleus/JDO implementation to this:

Suppose I have a POJO, `Hub` which represents a place/location:

```java
class Hub {
    List<Schedule> schedules; 
}
```

And a `Schedule` class to represent a specific day schedule of opening and closing of that place:

```
class Schedule {
    String day;
    LocalTime opens;
    LocalTime closes;
}
```

And then a query to those *Hubs*  to find which opens and closes during a specific day, say, query with this constraint:

```java
new Schedule().builder()
    .day("Monday")
    .opens(LocalTime.parse("09:00")
    .close(LocalTime.parse("17:00").build();
```

*Note that LocalTime is not Date*

So in this case we want to query for *Hubs* that are open on Mondays at 9am to 5pm.

1. What would be the Datanucleus/JDO implementation for the `Hub`?
2. What would be the query implementation to achieve the desired result as described?